# python2.5: No such file or directory

Tags: python, path, environment-variables

I have an internal tool which requires python; so it throws up this error during execution :

```
/bin/env: python2.5: No such file or directory
```

I had downloaded and installed py2.7 but this not solve the problem, so I have downloaded and installed py2.5.

```
-bash-4.1$ python --version
           Python 2.6.6
-bash-4.1$ which python
           /usr/bin/python
```

The path variable looks like this

```
 -bash-4.1$ echo $PATH
/scratch/bpurana/py25/:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/dev_infra/platform/bin:/usr/dev_infra/generic/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/ade/bin
```

I have tried the synlink solution too, listed in a couple of other posts too but since '/usr/bin/python' is a binary I am unable to symlink this.

modification of the script is not a feasible option.

Comment: Don't rely on the shebang or PATH, just run the script directly using the relevant python executable: i.e. `/full/path/to/python2.5 script.py`.

Comment: @ekhumoro I did try this but this is causing some other errors, can I make any more changes to the env to fix this error ?

Comment: What are the other errors? Edit your question and show the full tracebacks.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to install python2.5

or

`/bin/env: python2.5` to `/bin/env python` this, I believe is a better approach, if you can modify the file.

Comment: I cannot modify the file I already have a python 2.5 installed on the system